# Why "The 12-hour-system in English" rather than "The 12-hours-system in English"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have read in [this site](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/words/uhr.htm) about the Why "The 12-**hour**-system in English". Then my question is why "The 12-**hour**-system in English" rather than "The 12-**hours**-system in English"?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Pictures can't be searched or indexed, they're unfriendly to people with vision problems or slow internet connections, and they don't add anything to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 12 individual hours that make up the system, hence the 12 hour system. If I was saying there are 12 **hours** in a day, that's different because I'm talking about more than 1 hour. But this means the system consists of 12 individual hours.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately I really don't understand it.

Comment: Though their are 12 hours in the system, this is talking about the system as a whole. When you combine all the hours together, you get the system. The system is one object, not multiple. It's one system, but it contains multiple hours.

Comment: I think I got you. You mean something like 12 "hour system", or maybe the word "hour" functions as an adjective.

Comment: Yes that is correct.